# Create runnable jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jar

- I use sqljdbc driver for my project
- I have a "libs" folder to store all libraries
- To be able to connect to MSSQLServer I set "Native Library Location" for my sqljdbc4.jar. You see this native library location is in "libs" folder too

[image]

- Everything's OK,but when I create runnable jar file, I have connection problem

  ```
   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
  ```
- It is caused by "no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path"

What should I do to create a right runnable jar file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. Add sqljdbc_auth.dll of driver to System32, and no need to add native library location anymore

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add your `sqljdbc` driver to your `Classpath Variables` as follows:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables
```

With the 'New' button you can add the name and the path to your file.

Hope this helps !

Comment: more clearly bro! I have to both add my sqljdbc4.jar and set native library location for my sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: sorry I didn't understand .. you did add both of them and tried to recreate your runnable ?